# HTML context.drawimage not working

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

I am trying to display an image within a canvas with no luck. The context.filltext shows but the image does not. The image works if i display it directly but does not show when added to canvas. TaggedImage contains the text plus image.

```
function onCameraPicSuccess(imgData)
{

document.getElementById('tempImg').src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imgData;
var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById('lat').innerHTML);
var long = parseFloat(document.getElementById('long').innerHTML);
var accuracy = parseInt(document.getElementById('accuracy').innerHTML);

drawCanvas(lat, long);
var dataURL = document.getElementById("canvasPnl").toDataURL();
document.getElementById('taggedImage').src = dataURL;
document.getElementById('tempImg').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('taggedImage').style.display = 'block';

var radius = accuracy / 2;
var circle = L.circle([lat, long], radius, {
    color: 'yellow',
    fillColor: '#FF0',
    fillOpacity: 0.5
}).addTo(map).bindPopup("Captured picture <br />" + document.getElementById('taggedImage').outerHTML).openPopup();

}

 function drawCanvas(latitude, longitude)
{
var exif;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvasPnl");
var locationtxt = "Latitude: " + latitude + ", Longitude: " + longitude;

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
context.fillText(locationtxt, 10, 50);
var image = new Image();
image.onload = function(){

    context.drawImage(image, 10, 10, 200, 200);
    alert('image loaded');
};
image.src = document.getElementById('tempImg').src;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a wild guess, I think the error is when you specify the src attribute of the image in this line, because the browser may do some kind of internal translation from base64 to something else in the original image's src

You could try passing the `imgData` to the `drawCanvas` function and doing

`image.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imgData;`